# Trying to get full results using DayJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, dayjs

I'm trying to get the full results of this code execution, Right now what I get is only the date's of all values, but I need it so that all columns are displayed, so name and date. Can anyone help?

```js
const result = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Tom', date: '2022-05-17T22:00:00.000Z' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Joe', date: '2022-05-12T22:00:00.000Z' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Frederiko', date: '2022-05-23T22:00:00.000Z' },
    { id: 4, name: 'John', date: null },
    { id: 5, name: 'Boer', date: '2022-05-23T22:00:00.000Z' }
  ]
  
let time = dayjs().format('YYYY-MM-DD')
let eyy = result.filter(item1 => !result.find(item2 => item1.name == item2.name && dayjs(item2.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD') == time))

console.log(eyy);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs@1.8.21/dayjs.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your code appears to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/k6eL035j/   Exactly what is the problem you're having?   `result.filter` will return the source objects, if you were only getting the date, you would need `result.map` to convert the object to only return the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `result.filter` method can be simplified by removing the use of `result.find`, for example...

```js
const result = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Tom', date: '2022-05-17T22:00:00.000Z' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Joe', date: '2022-05-12T22:00:00.000Z' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Frederiko', date: '2022-05-23T22:00:00.000Z' },
    { id: 4, name: 'John', date: null },
    { id: 5, name: 'Boer', date: '2022-05-23T22:00:00.000Z' }
  ]
  
let time = dayjs().format('YYYY-MM-DD')
let eyy = result.filter(item => dayjs(item.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD') === time)

console.log(eyy);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs@1.8.21/dayjs.min.js"></script>
```

It's probably worth noting that depending where you are in the world the above will most likely not return anything because there are no dates matching today's date (May 24th).

---

From your comments it appears you want to modify the structure of the filtered results. To do this you can use the [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method...

```js
const result = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Tom', date: '2022-05-17T22:00:00.000Z' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Joe', date: '2022-05-12T22:00:00.000Z' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Frederiko', date: '2022-05-23T22:00:00.000Z' },
    { id: 4, name: 'John', date: null },
    { id: 5, name: 'Boer', date: '2022-05-24T22:00:00.000Z' }
  ];
  
let time = dayjs().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
let eyy = result.map(item => {
  return {
    name: item.name,
    date: dayjs(item.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
  };
});
    eyy = eyy.filter(item => item.date === time);
    

console.log(eyy);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs@1.8.21/dayjs.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yeah I probably forgot to mention that the DATE returns to the old node.js date, DayJS basically converts 2022-05-23T22:00:00.000Z into 2022-05-23, which Is what I need to happen. But for some reason it doesn't work here.

Comment: @Wake please see my updated answer.